# How to implement only one check box selected functionality to Chekc box list?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

How to implement only one check box selected from Check Box list with java script.

Here is script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
var previousCheckId;
     function toggle(chkBox) {
         if (chkBox.checked) {
              if (previousCheckId) {
                   document.getElementById(previousCheckId).checked = false;
              }
              previousCheckId = chkBox.getAttribute('id');
         }
     }
</script>
```

And here is my design:

```
<tr>
    <td class="BlackTextBold" align="right" height="25" width="32%"><div align="left"><strong>
        Product :</strong><span class="top-txt"><span style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family: Tahoma,sans-serif; color: red">*</span></span></div></td>
    <td height="20" width="68%">
         <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkLst" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
             RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="50%">
             <asp:ListItem onClick="toggle(this);" Value="EasyOFFICE">EasyOFFICE</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem onClick="toggle(this);" Value="EasyVAT">EasyVAT</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:CheckBoxList>
     </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td class="BlackTextBold" align="right" height="25" width="32%"><div align="left"><strong>
        PC Type :</strong><span class="top-txt"><span style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family: Tahoma,sans-serif; color: red">*</span></span></div></td>
    <td height="20" width="68%">
         <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkLst" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
             RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="30%">
             <asp:ListItem onClick="toggle(this);" Value="Server">Server</asp:ListItem>
             <asp:ListItem onClick="toggle(this);" Value="LAN">LAN</asp:ListItem>
         </asp:CheckBoxList>
     </td>
  </tr>
```

However this script works fine with One CheckBox list but when I just want to same thing to other CheckBox List then it's works with 4 one.

Comment: Why using same checklist again? This code is compiling? At least change the name of second checkbox list.

Answer (score 1):

Checkboxes imply that more than one choice can be made. If you only want to allow a single choice, use the RadioButtonList control: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.radiobuttonlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: They need to un check radiobutton, then also to uncheck you need javscript.

Comment: @ItiTyagi I don't see where the question mentions "unchecking" an option.

Answer (score 0):

It is what radio boxes are for...

but if you want to continue using checkboxes, a jQuery based solution can be to target only checked checkboxes within the same `td`

```
function toggle(chkBox) {
    if (chkBox.checked) {
        $(this).closest('td').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').not(this).prop('checked', false)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all the code will not compile as you have same name for the CheckBoxList.
Change the name of the second checkbox list and then try running the script, as there is no problem with the script.

```
<tr>
<td class="BlackTextBold" align="right" height="25" width="32%"><div align="left"><strong>
    Product :</strong><span class="top-txt"><span style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family: Tahoma,sans-serif; color: red">*</span></span></div></td>
<td height="20" width="68%">
     <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkLst" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
         RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="50%">
         <asp:ListItem onClick="toggle(this);" Value="EasyOFFICE">EasyOFFICE</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem onClick="toggle(this);" Value="EasyVAT">EasyVAT</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:CheckBoxList>
 </td>
 </tr>
  <tr>
<td class="BlackTextBold" align="right" height="25" width="32%"><div align="left"><strong>
    PC Type :</strong><span class="top-txt"><span style="font-size: 12.0pt; font-family: Tahoma,sans-serif; color: red">*</span></span></div></td>
<td height="20" width="68%">
     <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkLst1" runat="server" Font-Bold="True" 
         RepeatDirection="Horizontal" Width="30%">
         <asp:ListItem onClick="toggle(this);" Value="Server">Server</asp:ListItem>
         <asp:ListItem onClick="toggle(this);" Value="LAN">LAN</asp:ListItem>
     </asp:CheckBoxList>
 </td>
```

Comment: ok i changed it. but here problem is this toggle works for all 4 check box so i can check only one check box from that 4 one. here i just want to check one check box from chklst(1'st CheckBox) and other only one check box from chklst1(2'nd CheckBox).